# How do I specify the position of a width parameter?

Tags: linux, bash, printf

Apologies if this has been posted before. I've been searching all over and can't find an answer.

According to `man printf`, "FORMAT controls the output as in C printf." It refers to `printf(3)`.

According to `man 3 printf`, you can specify a variable width in a given position. It says:

> Instead of a decimal digit string one may write … "`*m$`" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the precision is given in the m-th argument … which must be of type int.

This is the part where I'm struggling. To give a simple example, suppose I wish to print a string with width 14.

```
$ printf '[%14s]\n' Something
[     Something]
```

I can use a variable instead:

```
$ WIDTH=14
$ printf '[%*s]\n' ${WIDTH} Something
[     Something]
```

The tricky part comes when I want to tell `printf` that the width argument is in a different position. To keep things simple for this example, I'll leave it where it is, in position 1. Following the instructions, I write the following.

*Built-in version:*

```
$ printf '[%*1$s]\n' ${WIDTH} Something
bash: printf: `1': invalid format character
```

*Version in `/usr/bin`:*

```
$ /usr/bin/printf '[%*1$s]\n' ${WIDTH} Something
[/usr/bin/printf: %*1: invalid conversion specification
```

Even using the example from the manual gives an error.

*Built-in version:*

```
$ printf '%2$*1$d' 6 34
bash: printf: `$': invalid format character
```

*Version in `/usr/bin`:*

```
$ /usr/bin/printf '%2$*1$d' 6 34
/usr/bin/printf: %2$: invalid conversion specification
```

As you can see, I get an error every time. I have struggled to see what I'm doing wrong, and I simply cannot find any example online.

How should this be formatted, please, or is the manual just wrong?

- Lubuntu 18.04
- GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- builtin printf: unknown version
- /usr/bin/printf printf (GNU coreutils) 8.28

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the extension that comes from Single UNIX Specification to C `printf` function to specify the position of positional parameter with `$` is not supported in bash `printf` and I doubt it's supported in any of shells `printf` implementations. I believe the reason is that it requires additional work from the developers, while it's very rarely used extension.

> is the manual just wrong?
>
> FORMAT controls the output as in C printf.

You are reading the documentation for GNU version of printf, taken from the amazing Linux man-pages project. I would say C printf is documented [in the C standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1).

Comment: Why is implementing it hard if it's already implemented in `printf(3)`?

Comment: I think you ask another question, why shell implementation of `printf` doesn't use glibc `printf`? Because all inputs are strings, and you have to convert them (and not to tie your shell to glibc, could be another reason). So you end up [writing your own printf like in bash](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/printf.def#L327). As to `Why is implementing it hard`, well, I tried once to implement my printf version with it and it was hard for me to implement it.

Comment: @Barmar one reason might be that bash adds extra conversion specifiers like %b, %q and %(fmt)T to printf, so they re-implement it as a builtin rather than using libc's printf

Comment: Besides, unlike libc's printf, shell's printf uses the format string until it exhausts the argument list. It doesn't seem easy to implement both that and indexed specifiers

Comment: @oguzismail That's a very good point. The loop assumes that arguments will be processed in order, and it requires `printf()` to do its own format processing to keep track of how many arguments are used.

Answer (score 2):

If your shell's printf doesn't support parameter indexing, you can still call Perl to the rescue!

```
$ perl -we 'printf q([%1$*2$d]), @ARGV' 36 6
[    36]
```

See [printf](http://p3rl.org/printf) and, more importantly, [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf).

Comment: Or gawk, its printf supports numbered argument conversion specs as well

Comment: Thank you for this, but I can't seem to make it work for a non-numeric printable item ( the equivalent of`printf '[%*1$s]\n' ${WIDTH} Something`). I don't know perl, so that would explain why.

Comment: No need to know Perl: `perl -we 'printf q([%2$*1$s]), @ARGV'  16 Something`